# convert object (with optional keys) to array of keys

Tags: typescript

I have this function:

```
export interface KeyValue<K, V> {
  key: K;
  value: V;
}

declare function transform<K extends string, V>(input: Record<K, V>): Array<KeyValue<K, V>>;

interface Foo {
  foo: string;
  bar?: number;
}

declare const foo: Foo;

const a = transform(foo);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgaWAE8A1TAGwFdgAefAGjhID44BvAKDjgGtiAuAgG4ucAG4VqgkiIC%20HDgBNg2cpih50lJNhgIISODCiYkAZ3TQAtnTihUSRWbhnjyAOaMWACmRhKMIIASirQinRezACUggCCUCZEdMRkVLQMTMzMIhzIqBg4eABiEBDsopYQgq5QHiLcAEbqAPyCSJRWDWhyCsqq6njYBq5wlYIlEDlD5vCYcAC8RibmllBW3pVRQkA)

It works great for types without optional keys but not when there is one or multiple optional keys.

How could I improve the typing to allow this optional keys ?

Comment: `Partial<Record<...>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```ts
declare function transform<K extends keyof T, T>(input: T): Array<{ key: K, value: T[K] }>;
```